# How can i convert binary codes to png image in qml?

Tags: xml, image, qt, binary-data, qml

In qml, i am using xml file to get some information from server. In this xml file there is a field as
< image>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA2AAAALKCAYAAABUYjK........< /image>.
 I am using XmlListModel and ListView for other field but how can i convert this code to png image.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't try myself, but if QML supports the data URI scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), try

```
Image {
    source: "data:image/png;base64," + model.imageData
}
```

Comment: I tried, it works. This might be the best and shortest solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a custom [`QDeclarativeImageProvider`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdeclarativeimageprovider.html), which creates an image from the encoded data.
Then you can do something like this in your delegate:

```qml
// ...

Image {
    source: "image://encodedimage/" + model.imageData
}

// ...
```

Have a look at [this example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/declarative-cppextensions-imageprovider.html), it might be a starting point for your implementation.

If the image is base64 encoded, then you can create an image like that (not tested):

```cpp
QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromBase64(imageDataString.toAscii());
QImage image = QImage::fromData(ba, "PNG");
```